# Emulating HTML5 features on legacy browsers using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

Is there something like a HTML5 enabling script, that simulates the function of new HTML5 elements for older browsers?

I know there is [html5shim](http://html5shim.googlecode.com), but that only makes the elements style-able.

I was more looking for a solution, that makes new HTML5 elements behave like they should.

Here are some examples:

- [A script that simulates the placeholder attribute](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-html5-placeholder-text)
- [A script that simulates form validation](http://forrst.com/posts/HTML5_Form_jQuery_fallback-hTO)
- [A script that simulates the details-element](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-details-jquery)
- [A script that simulates the datalist-element](http://miketaylr.com/code/datalist.html)

Is there a solution, that provides all of them as one? And all the other new HTML5-Elements as well?

Comment: There is no current solution that emulates all the emulatable features of the HTML5 spec. If you would write one that aggregates all the solutions that would be great o/.

Comment: e.g. make `<video>`, `<audio>`, `<canvas>` etc... work in older browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTML5 polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills)

has a large list of all polyfills.

There is no large project that "emulates" all of HTML5. Mind you [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/download/) is probably the most complete project to that end.

My personal recommendation is find and use polyfills as and when you need them. Loading less features is always better.